# c++/ROS2 get QoS based on topic name

Tags: c++, ros2

I am working on a ROS2 project, I don't have access to the publisher, and I want to subscribe to a topic. The issue is that I don't know the QoS of the published message, and thus subscribing to it raises a warning like :

```
[WARN] [1705394710.630533309] [rosbag2_player]: New subscription discovered on topic '/my_topic_name', requesting incompatible QoS. No messages will be sent to it. Last incompatible policy: RELIABILITY_QOS_POLICY
```

Is there any way to retrieve, with rclcpp, the QoS of a given topic solely using the name ?
I know it's possible when calling:

```
ros2 topic info /my_topic_name --verbose
```

But I need to access it via rclcpp. I have checked online and really couldn't find a proper answer... which is weird cause it seems to me smth that should be doable right ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK so as it happens, I figured out a way to do it, using the `get_publishers_info_by_topic` method

here is a snippet of my POC (so not yet the cleanest code, but it gives the idea):

```
  auto qos_profile = rclcpp::QoS{10}; // Default QoS

  auto topidEndPointVec = this->get_publishers_info_by_topic(topic_details.name, false);
  if (topidEndPointVec.size() > 0)
  {
    qos_profile = topidEndPointVec[0].qos_profile();
  }
```

And now I can create a subscriber to `topic_details.name` using the `qos_profile`